# factorial Vs power sequence

Tags: factorial, exponentiation

What sequence is dominant between

$ f(n) = n!$ and
$ g(n) = 2^n$ or (or $a^n$)

I mean
$ f/g \to 0 $ or $\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) states that:

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\, \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}} = 1
$$

Or:

$$
n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
$$

Which means that $n!$ grows faster that $a^n$. This is easy to see intuitively, given how $a^n$ consists of $n$ constant terms, whereas $n!$ consists of $n$ increasing terms. For large enough $n$, $n!$ will be larger.

Answer (score 3):

The factorial grows faster because it consists of $n$ factors of *increasing* size, while the power $a^n$ consists of $n$ factors of constant size.

Comment: you could give a simple proof, something like n! > (n/4)^n for n>5 maybe

Comment: well I see your point n! is > a^n for n>a/2 right?

Comment: @caub, maybe you mean n/2 > a? Otherwise it would follow, for example, that 8! > 14^8 (because 8 > 14/2) which is obviously not true.